# Vertical Bullet alignment in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="overflow">This is some more text</span></li>
    <li><span class="overflow">This is some more text</span></li>
    <li><span class="overflow">This is some more text</span></li>
    <li><span class="overflow">This is some more text</span></li>
    <li><span class="overflow" style="display: inline-block;">This is some more text This is some more text This is some more text</span><br /><span>This is some more text This is some more text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Accompanied with this CSS:

```
ul { list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: circle; width: 150px; }

.overflow { display: block; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; }
```

For some perculiar reason, the list items with the `overflow: hidden` span's don't have any bullet points in Chrome.

Well, all except the last one, apparently changing `display: block` to `display: inline-block` on the overflow css class remedies this. However this gives you another problem as the bullet point is centrally aligned vertically.

I really hope that all makes sense ... here is a fiddle to help illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/zUxTD/

In conclusion, is there any way to vertically align bullet points in Chrome? If not, then does anybody have any idea why the bullet points are not appearing on the other list items (I assume this is a bug of some sort)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you looking to change the bullet's vertical alignment on the one list item in your example that spans multiple lines? If so, what alignment should it have?

Comment: Basically yes, it should be vertically aligned top

Comment: Wouldn't `vertical-align:top` as the only rule for you overflow class do the trick?

Comment: Awesome! Not sure why I didn't try that, but put that as an answer and I'm happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
.overflow { display: block; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; }
```

to

```
.overflow { vertical-align:top; }
```

Comment: I need all of those styles assigned to the overflow class, but simply appending `vertical-align: top` seems to work too :)